# R code not working to merge data (unduplicate) in columns based on identical values

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to do some data wrangling on a tibble (dataframe) using dplyr, to unduplicate records, where if an id shows up twice, the resulting record will contain the same values if they are all identical, or an NA if there is a discrepancy in one of the records.  For example, if I have df:

```
id       date        amount     tag
---      ----        ------     ---
1        2018-01-03  10         big
2        2019-01-16  20         small
3        2020-01-05  30         big
3        2001-03-04  30         big
1        2018-01-03  5          big
```

The result should look like:

```
id       date        amount     tag
---      ----        ------     ---
1        2018-01-03  NA         big
2        2019-01-16  20         small
3        NA          30         big
```

Based on other answers I've found on stack overflow, I have tried various methods of using summarise_all including:

```r
new_df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(function(x) ifelse(all(x[1] == x),x[1],NA))
```

```r
new_df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(list(~ if(all(.[1] == .)) .[1] else NA))
```

```r
new_df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(funs(if(all(.[1] == .)) .[1] else NA))
```

Since I was able to use `ifelse(all(x[1] == x),x[1],NA)` on its own with a vector and it worked fine, I thought that would work with summarise_all. But when I use it with `summarise_all` or the other variants I show above, I get the error:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots): Column `date` can't promote group 2 to character
```

I suspect I just need to make a small tweak to my code to get it to work, but I've been working on this all day, and I don't know why it isn't working...  So any help that the community can provide would be appreciated.  This is the first time I've actually asked a question on stack overflow, because I almost always can find the answer from other people's questions :-)  Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the solution:

```
d %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise_all(~if(n_distinct(.) == 1) first(.) else c(NA, .)[1])
```

This is actually a little tricky. You'd think one could write simply:

```
d %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise_all(~if(n_distinct(.) == 1) first(.) else NA)
```

Which is just an alternative to your `if (all ...) ... else ...`, using some more `dplyr` functions.

However, `dplyr` doesn't like simply giving `NA`, but rather you need to be type specific. E.g. you need to provide `NA_character_` or `NA_integer_` etc to match the correct data type. This is why your code is failing, the error says that group 2 (i.e. `id == 2` in this case) is failing to be "promoted" to character. This means that the `NA` provided there in column `Date` isn't being coerced to character and a new column is failing to be created.

Since you don't want to code all the correct `NA` types, I use a little trick here. Using `c(NA, .)[1]` to combine an `NA` value with the original variable will coerce that `NA` to the correct type, which I then use. You can probably use other tricks to get the correct `NA` too.

Comment: That worked great, and I appreciate the explanation.  I thought it would be some type of data type error, but I didn't know where it was.  I also appreciate you showing the dplyr functions. I prefer to go as much tidyverse as I can when writing code.

Comment: It's really not an error that's very easy to figure out, to be honest.